# Вместо того(,) чтобы

Tags: пунктуация

"Cначала мать воспитанника, вместо того(,) чтобы обратиться к воспитателю, работой которого она была недовольна, связалась с заведующим. Затем руководитель повторил ту же ошибку: вместо того(,) чтобы сразу переговорить с воспитателем, он обратился к ее коллегам".

В первом случае я бы не ставила запятую, а во втором случае затрудняюсь с решением.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Cначала мать воспитанника, вместо того чтобы обратиться к воспитателю, работой которого она была недовольна, связалась с заведующим.

Союз не расчленяется, если придаточная конструкция находится внутри главного предложения.

2) Затем руководитель повторил ту же ошибку: вместо того чтобы сразу переговорить с воспитателем, он обратился к ее коллегам".

Расчленение союза факультативное, в препозиции придаточного чаще не расчленяется. При расчленении подчеркивается значимость придаточной части, так как ударение падает на местоименную часть союза, содержание которой раскрывает придаточное.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Союзы со значением сопоставления и сравнения МЕЖДУ ТЕМ КАК, В ТО ВРЕМЯ КАК, ПО МЕРЕ ТОГО КАК, ТОГДА КАК, ПОДОБНО ТОМУ КАК, ВМЕСТО ТОГО ЧТОБЫ  не расчленяются в любой позиции в предложении.

Вот некоторые примеры:

По мере того как бричка близилась к крыльцу, глаза Манилова делались всё веселее. Подобно тому как магнит притягивает к себе железо, большой город притягивает людей.  Гребцы выбивались из сил, между тем как лодку относило всё дальше от берега.  Она решила бороться, тогда как раньше только плакала и худела.  Но утром пошёл дождь, в то время как до этого стояла сухая и солнечная погода.  Он, вместо того чтобы спуститься по Волге, поднялся до Камышина.

Comment: Вера, а как поступают в случае простановки этой самой факультативной запятой? Можно ли при этом убрать ту, что перед "вместо"? Она мне страшно не нравится: мать вместо одного сделала другое - изначально здесь нет запятой; вместо чего? - вместо того, чтобы (...,) . Или этим правилом движет идея "изымаемости обособленного оборота" (по аналогии с ", и если..., то" / "и, если...,")?

Comment: Александр, я пока размышляла над вашим вопросом, вспомнила, что этот союз  не расчленяется в любой позиции.

Comment: Спасибо, придётся мне делать над собой усилие :)

Answer (score 0):

Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом ''вместо того(,) чтобы'', выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. При этом союз может целиком входить в придаточную часть (и не разделяться запятой), но может и расчленяться (в этом случае запятая ставится между частями союза, перед словом ''чтобы'').

В приведенных вами  примерах,  запятая между союзом не ставится, т.к. придаточное находится внутри главного. 
Подробнее об этом здесь: [Грамота.ру.](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach3/)

> Вера, ваш ответ абсолютно верный. Что вас заставило засомневаться?