# "вместо того(,) чтобы " - расчленяется или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

> — У меня нет времени излагать тебе историю Гондора, хотя было бы
>   неплохо, если бы ты изучил из нее что-нибудь**<kbd>,</kbd> вместо того<kbd>,</kbd> чтобы** 
>   болтаться по Хоббитширским лесам и разорять птичьи гнезда!

(фрагмент из книги "Возвращение короля", Дж. Толкин, перевод Маториной В.А.)

Подскажите, правильно ли расставлены запятые при союзе **вместо того чтобы**? Кажется, они здесь в явном избытке и вторая запятая не нужна (приведённый пример не подпадает ни под одно из  условий, когда составной подчинительный союз может расчленяться).

Фрагмент из другого перевода:

> — Видишь ли, господин Пипин, у меня сейчас нет времени учить тебя истории Гондора, хотя было бы лучше, если бы ты интересовался ею, вместо того чтобы искать птичьи гнёзда да болтаться по лесам Шира.

Здесь знаки препинания стоят как положено и других вариантов их расстановки нет?

---

---

**Дополнительно:**

Не хватает баллов репутации, поэтому не могу спросить в той теме, в которой увидел интересный мне комментарий ([Вместо того(,) чтобы](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/50265/%D0%92%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B))

> Союзы со значением сопоставления и сравнения МЕЖДУ ТЕМ КАК, В ТО ВРЕМЯ
>   КАК, ПО МЕРЕ ТОГО КАК, ТОГДА КАК, ПОДОБНО ТОМУ КАК, **ВМЕСТО ТОГО ЧТОБЫ**
>   не расчленяются в любой позиции в предложении.

Где установлена даннная норма?

Насколько мне известно, этот союз может расчленяться согласно общему для таких случаев правилу:

> > Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом «вместо того(,) чтобы», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. При этом союз может целиком входить в придаточную часть (и не разделяться запятой), но может и расчленяться (в этом случае запятая ставится между частями союза, перед словом «чтобы»).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**ВМЕСТО ТОГО(,) ЧТОБЫ, союз**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_288)

Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом «вместо того(,) чтобы», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. При этом союз может целиком входить в придаточную часть (и не разделяться запятой), но может и расчленяться (в этом случае запятая ставится между частями союза, перед словом «чтобы»). О факторах, влияющих на расстановку знаков препинания, см. в Прил. 3.

Сказавши это, он, вместо того чтобы идти домой, пошел совершенно в противную сторону, сам того не подозревая. Н. Гоголь, Шинель. Но вместо того, чтобы спуститься к речке, мы зашли в какую-то ложбину и очутились перед пустым сарайчиком... И. Тургенев, Стук... стук... стук! Вместо того чтобы обсыпать столб заслуженными ругательствами, Гараська обратился к нему с кроткими упреками, носившими несколько фамильярный оттенок. Л. Андреев, Баргамот и Гараська.

---

**— У меня нет времени излагать тебе историю Гондора, хотя было бы неплохо, если бы ты изучил из нее что-нибудь, вместо того чтобы болтаться по Хоббитширским лесам и разорять птичьи гнезда!** - вторая запятая лишняя.

Во втором переводе знаки на месте.

Кстати, в обоих переводах три "бы" на предложение (однако)! Если два "бы" необходимы, то одно из заменяют на "б", а от третьего и вовсе избавляются.

---

Приложение 3. [ПУНКТУАЦИЯ В КОНСТРУКЦИЯХ С СОСТАВНЫМИ ПОДЧИНИТЕЛЬНЫМИ СОЮЗАМИ](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach3/)

---

К дополнению в вопросе:

[**МЕЖ(ДУ) ТЕМ КАК, союз**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_414)

Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом «меж(ду) тем как», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. Между частями союза запятая не ставится.

Алеша возвратился в дом и весь вечер просидел один в классных комнатах, между тем как на другой половине часу до одиннадцатого пробыли гости... А. Погорельский, Черная курица, или Подземные жители. Тогда я приостанавливал пальбу, выходил из кузова и извинялся перед гостеприимным трактирщиком в причиненном беспокойстве, между тем как кучер распрягал лошадей, поил их у бадьи, и мы предавались мирному, хотя и короткому отдыху в одинокой гостинице. В. Короленко, Парадокс. ...Чьи-то черные, точно вырезанные из черного дерева силуэты двигаются вокруг костра, меж тем как гигантские тени от них ходят по яблоням. И. Бунин, Антоновские яблоки. Представляю себе этих болванов, где-нибудь кутящих и развратничающих, меж тем как дело стоит на месте... Б. Окуджава, Путешествие дилетантов.

---

[**ПОДОБНО ТОМУ(,) КАК, союз**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_539)

Синтаксические конструкции, начинающиеся с союза «подобно тому как», выделяются знаками препинания (запятыми). При этом первый знак препинания может ставиться либо перед составным союзом, либо между его частями (перед словом «как»). О факторах, влияющих на расстановку знаков препинания, см. в Приложении 3.

Подобно тому как первоначальное расположение и нерасположение к незнакомому человеку определял в большей или меньшей степени внешний облик его, так и первое ощущение неизвестного города (и не только за границей) подчиняло Никитина доверчивой силе толкающего любопытства… Ю. Бондарев, Берег. Поэзия насыщает сердце народа подобно тому, как мириады капелек влаги насыщают воздух над Данией. К. Паустовский, Сказочник. Но, подобно тому как золотая роза старого мусорщика предназначалась для счастья Сюзанны, так и наше творчество предназначается для того, чтобы красота земли, призыв к борьбе за счастье, радость и свободу, широта человеческого сердца и сила разума преобладали над тьмой и сверкали, как незаходящее солнце. К. Паустовский, Золотая роза.

---

[**В ТО ВРЕМЯ(,) КАК, союз**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_127)

Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом «в то время(,) как», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. При этом союз может целиком входить в придаточную часть (и не разделяться запятой), но может и расчленяться (в этом случае запятая ставится между частями союза, перед словом «как»). О факторах, влияющих на расстановку знаков препинания, см. в Прил. 3.

Он был женат на бедной дворянке, которая умерла в родах, в то время как он находился в отъезжем поле. А. Пушкин, Барышня-крестьянка. Мне смешно вспомнить, как сильно пахло от нас троих помадой в то время, как мы стали спускаться по лестнице. Л. Толстой, Детство. Ей даже досадно стало на нее за то, что она оправилась как раз в то время, как было послано письмо. Л. Толстой, Анна Каренина.

Если придаточная часть сложноподчиненного предложения стоит перед главной, запятая между частями союза «в то время как» обычно не ставится (постановка запятой допустима, но такое пунктуационное оформление считается устаревшим).

В то время как мы сидели по целым часам на заборе, вглядываясь в зеленоватую воду, из глубины бадьи то и дело подымались стайками эти странные существа… В. Короленко, Парадокс.

---

[**ПО МЕРЕ ТОГО(,) КАК, союз**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_562)

Синтаксические конструкции, начинающиеся с союза «по мере того как», выделяются знаками препинания. При этом первый знак препинания может ставиться либо перед составным союзом, либо между его частями (перед словом «как»). О факторах, влияющих на расстановку знаков препинания, см. в Приложении 3.

Рассказывая о вине, Кудряшов попивал его и, по мере того как пил, оживлялся. В. Гаршин, Встреча. А раненые все поступали… Приток их рос по мере того, как на фронте возрастала мощь нашего наступления. Б. Полевой, Повесть о настоящем человеке. По мере того как она шла, лицо ее прояснялось, дыхание становилось реже и покойнее, и она опять пошла ровным шагом. И. Гончаров, Обломов.

---

А вот "тогда как" может быть союзом и наречием с союзом: постановка знаков разнится, см.:

[**ТОГДА КАК, союз; наречие + союз**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_732)

1. Союз. То же, что «но, хотя, в то время как». Синтаксические конструкции, начинающиеся с союза «тогда как», выделяются знаками препинания (запятыми). При этом первый знак препинания ставится перед словом «тогда», а не перед словом «как».

Замечательно, что выходцы-родоначальники передали свой красивый тип до позднейшего потомства одним мужчинам, тогда как белокурые женщины сохранили свой местный – и надо сказать правду – весьма некрасивый тип. А. Фет, Бедные люди. Во всех других странах государь вышел из народа, тогда как в Японии, напротив того, народ имеет честь происходить от государя, который непосредственно происходит от богов. А. Битов, Япония.

2. Наречие + союз. Перед «как» ставится запятая.

Идти на рать – не песню орать: хвались тогда, как сможешь; а бог даст, и сам буйную голову положишь. О. Сомов, В поле съезжаются, родом не считаются.