# О составном союзе "вместо того чтобы"

Tags: союзы

1) **Значение союза "вместо того чтобы"**

Союз "вместо того чтобы" вроде бы используется при сопоставлении двух ситуаций, но как определить его точное значение (соответствие, несоответствие или что-то другое) и как определить тип придаточного? (Что-то не получается найти в грамматиках точное название).

2) (а) Вместо того, чтобы строить мосты, люди предпочитают возводить стены.

(б) Эти греки, вместо того, чтобы работать, всё критиковали.

Как видно из примеров, **союз свободно расчленяется по желанию автора**, да и в недавнем ответе на похожий вопрос говорилось о возможности постановки **двух запятых** в предложениях, где есть составные союзы. Но вот Розенталь говорил, кажется, об **одной запятой**, а Лопатин ничего не говорит про две запятые.

**Так почему же допускается такое расчленение?**

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: ["вместо того(,) чтобы " - расчленяется или нет?](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418718/%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%87%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82)

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, Галина ответила достаточно полно ["вместо того(,) чтобы " - расчленяется или нет?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418718/%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82).

Допускается, потому что допускается правилами, и Розенталем в том числе.

Тип придаточного - сопоставительное. Ср.: Он скорее бы умер, чем ее в такую минуту покинул (Дост.); Для меня легче сидеть на бочке с порохом, чем говорить с женщиной (Чех.). (Я лучше бы сидел на бочке с порохом, вместо того чтобы разговаривать с женщиной.)

Кроме союза "чем" в придаточных сопоставительных предложениях может употребляться также союз "вместо того чтобы" или его стилистически сниженный синоним "вместо чтобы": Я, вместо чтоб скакать по стряпчим, по судам, платить и кланяться, - к прелестнице поеду, а ты покуда здесь останься, проповедуй! (Гриб.). Вместо того, чтоб исправить несправедливость..., вот как он поступает (С.-Щ., переписка); Раскольников отдал перо, но вместо того, чтоб
встать и уйти, положил оба локтя на стол и стиснул руками голову (Дост.).

Comment: Действительно, у Розенталя тоже говорится о расчленении. Но вот о двух запятых ничего нигде не говорится. Вряд ли в приведенных вами примерах две запятые можно считать оправданными.

Comment: О каких ДВУХ запятых речь? Да, запятая или перед союзом, или внутри него.Я, вместо чтоб скакать по стряпчим, по судам, Платить и кланяться, - к прелестнице поеду, -перед союзом.Раскольников отдал перо, но вместо того, чтоб встать и уйти, положил оба локтя на стол и стиснул руками голову.-внутри, там же нет второй, перед союзом. О чём речь? В примере Веры "Эти греки, вместо того, чтобы работать, всё критиковали".  что-то авторское, к сожалению, автора не знаю, мы не можем судить о его грамотности, видимо, захотелось поставить паузу.

Comment: Людмила, именно о примере Веры и идет речь. Людмила, но ведь нигде не оговаривается такое употребление.

Comment: Сопоставительные предложения обычно имеют дополнительные значения: соответствие, несоответствие, противопоставление, уступка. Меня как раз интересовало частное значение союза "вместо того чтобы", но я нашла его в книге. Это сравнительно-сопоставительные предложения с дополнительной оценкой, когда одна ситуация оценивается как более предпочтительная, целесообразная,чем другая.

Comment: Союз часто расчленяется неправильно, например: "Госорганы раздумывают по 9 месяцев над поручениями Президента, вместо того, чтобы их немедленно выполнять"."Дон Хуан делал все так же, как вначале дон Хенаро, но затем, вместо того, чтобы прыгнуть вверх, он стал вращаться как гимнаст".

Comment: Да, Вы правы: то же самое говорится в Русской грамматике.